# How to setup Kerberos realm without domain name

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I'm currently setting up Kerberos for an Ambari Hortonworks environment. For a number of reasons, I'm unable to use a distinct domain name as the realm name for this install. This is strange because - from what I read -  the realm name is just set to the domain name by convention. In theory it can be any ASCII string.

For this Ambari environment I'm essentially trying to set up Kerberos where

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = FOOBAR
```

In fact, my current krb5.conf looks something like this:

```
[libdefaults]
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_realm = FOOBAR
ticket_lifetime = 24h
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
rdns = false
default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
#default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
#default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

[domain_realm]
#Not sure how to use this mapping property in this case
FOOBAR = FOOBAR
.FOOBAR = FOOBAR

[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

[realms]
FOOBAR = {
admin_server = {admin ip adress}
kdc = {kdc ip address}
}
```

/etc/hosts

```
{kdc ip address} FOOBAR kdc
```

One ought to be able to short-circuit the DNS check with the hosts file. But I can't seem to get Kerberos working this way. All the documentation I found so far online describes the nice, safe setup following the DNS convention.
Can anyone point to a tutorial, or describe the necessary steps to make Kerberos work without a domain name?

Comment: _"the realm name is just set to the domain name by convention"_ > what do you mean by "domain"? A network domain, or an Active Directory domain _(which is implicitly a Kerberos realm but spelled in lowercase)_?

Comment: Kerberos is meant for strong athentication over an unsecure network. It requires a DNS authority and proper DNS config (reverse lookups) to reduce its attack surface. Also requires that systems clocks be in sync, etc etc. **Security** is not something you ask an intern to set up in 10 min after two beers, sorry...

Comment: Replace `{admin ip adress}` with `{canonical DNS name of the host running a KDC service on default port 88}` or specify another port if necessary; if you have a pool of KDCs (which is really a good idea for obvious availability reasons) then add one line per KDC, and check about the Java-specific entry about timeout (that was undocumented before Java9 and also had a silly default of 30s)

Comment: For future readers; I did manage to get this working using a non-registered DNS name. I did not find any tutorials on this, so I just spend some time flipping config options on/off.

Comment: So provide the options you used and make an answer, and then self-mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of helpful response I'll just share what I end up using (works but might not be optimal)

```
[libdefaults]
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_realm = FOOBAR
ticket_lifetime = 24h
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
#default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
#default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

[domain_realm]
FOOBAR = FOOBAR
.FOOBAR = FOOBAR

[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

[realms]
FOOBAR = {
admin_server = {admin_server ip}
kdc = {kdc_server ip}
}
```

In addition, be sure to add the ip addresses and hostnames for all machines in the cluster to /etc/hosts files.